Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n \choose 3}}{n!}$

Evalute the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n \choose 3}}{n!}.$$

A simpler case can be considered for ${n \choose 2}$: We note that ${n \choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ is even exactly when $n\equiv 0,1 \bmod 4$, meaning that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n \choose 2}}{n!} 
=+\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!}
\color{red}{
            -\frac 1 {2!}  -\frac{1}{3!}
            }
+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!}
\color{red}{- \frac{1}{6!}- \frac{1}{7!}} +\cdots.$$
We recognize this as $\sin(1)+\cos(1) = \sqrt2 \sin(1+\frac \pi 4)$.
For our case, similarly,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n \choose 3}}{n!} 
=+\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!}
\color{red}{-\frac{1}{3!}}+
\frac{1}{4!} + \frac{1}{5!} + \frac{1}{6!}
\color{red}{-\frac{1}{7!}}
 +\cdots.$$
This is less obvious; is there a simple way of finding this value using trigonometric functions?

By the same approach, the result is $\sin(1) + \frac{e+e^{-1}}2$.

@Pranay yes or more simply $\sin(1)+\cosh(1)$

Try writing out $\left( \begin{matrix} n \ 3 \end{matrix}  \right)$ for about 10-20 terms with a calculator and see if you can detect any kind of pattern to the odd-even behavior

Then write down the coefficients for $\sin(1), \cos(1), \sinh(1), \cosh(1)$ and really see @Gwen’s and @Pranay’s result


Solve the value:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{\binom n 3}}{n!} 
= \dfrac{1}{0!}+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}-\dfrac{1}{3!}+\dfrac{1}{4!}+\dfrac{1}{5!}+\dfrac{1}{6!}-\dfrac{1}{7!}+\cdots$$

\begin{align}
& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2n)!} = \cosh(1) \\
& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} = \sin(1) \\
\ \\
& \dfrac{1}{0!} + \dfrac{1}{2!} + \dfrac{1}{4!} + \dfrac{1}{6!} + \cdots = \cosh(1) \\
& \dfrac{1}{1!} - \dfrac{1}{3!} + \dfrac{1}{5!} - \dfrac{1}{7!} + \cdots = \sin(1) \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{\binom n 3}}{n!} 
= \dfrac{1}{0!}+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}-\dfrac{1}{3!}+\dfrac{1}{4!}+\dfrac{1}{5!}+\dfrac{1}{6!}-\dfrac{1}{7!}+\cdots \\
& = \left( \dfrac{1}{0!} + \dfrac{1}{2!} + \dfrac{1}{4!} + \dfrac{1}{6!} + \cdots \right) + \left( \dfrac{1}{1!} - \dfrac{1}{3!} + \dfrac{1}{5!} - \dfrac{1}{7!} + \cdots \right) \\
& = \cosh(1)+\sin(1). \blacksquare
\end{align}
Addition) Prove that $\binom n 3$ is odd for $n$ such that $n \equiv 3 (\mod 4)$ and even for others.
For $n=4k+3$, $\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} = \dfrac{(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)}{6}$ is odd value.
For other values, the numerator contains $4k$, so the value is even.
